# Error making a sub-array

Tags: java, arrays

I've an array that has a size of 5 and the following elements -

```
int[] a = new int[] {0, 10, 20, 30, 40};
```

What I want to do is make a sub array which will have elements from a[index] till a[index + size]

In order to achieve the purpose this is what I am doing. I am making a class constructor this way -

```
public CoolName(int index, int size, int[] array) {
    int counter = 0;
    this.a = array;
    while(counter < size) {
        if(index <= (size + index)) {
            array[counter] = array[index];
            counter++;
            index++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

}
```

However when I try to output it using my main method, this is what gets printed -

```
Subarray after modification:
s[0]: 20
s[1]: 300
s[2]: 20
s[3]: 30
s[4]: 40
```

**Problem** - I just want elements from index till index + size that is, if I pass the index of 2 and size of 2, I just want in total 2 elements (which is the size).

This was my expected output -

```
Subarray after modification:
s[0]: 20
s[1]: 300
```

So basically, I didn't want the extra elements to be displayed. I know that its printing all elements cause I set `this.array = a` and so it got the size of the original array.

However, can someone please tell me a possible fix for this issue? Thanks for addressing my question!

Comment: Shouldn't you be making a copy of the array?

Comment: And why are you using a Class constructor, and not a simple method ?

Comment: Well I tried to do it that way and then I was getting NullPointerException cause I am setting this constructor inside a method that has the return type of an interface. So basically I do something like `Interface name = new CoolName(index, size, array)` and then return the object (name) . I honestly don't have much idea how to do it though

Comment: @FlorentBayle I know really wish that was allowed but for this project I am not allowed to do it any other way.

Comment: @user3397222 Just create a constructor that declares int[] subarray and set it equal to the int[] array returned by the method provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to create a copy of your array:

```
public CoolName(int index, int size, int[] array) {
    this.a = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, index, index+size);
}
```

Comment: @aliteralmind I gave you an up-vote :-). Your answer is still relevant for people using java < 6, so it's a good idea to let it here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). Like this:

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code java CopyArraySubset}</P>
 **/
public class CopyArraySubset  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      int[] origInts = new int[] {0, 10, 20, 30, 40};
      int startIdx = 2;
      int newArrayLen = origInts.length - startIdx;
      int[] intsSubset = new int[newArrayLen];
      System.arraycopy(origInts, startIdx, intsSubset, 0, newArrayLen);

      System.out.println("origInts=" + Arrays.toString(origInts));
      System.out.println("intsSubset=" + Arrays.toString(intsSubset));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]java CopyArraySubset
origInts=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
intsSubset=[20, 30, 40]
```

Comment: Since Java 6 there has been a method `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(..)` that does exactly what you did in the 3 lines starting with `int newArrayLen`

Comment: Good to know. I'll leave it as is, though, since @FlorentBayle's answer already uses that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] getSubArray(int[] array, int index, int size) {
  int[] subArray = new int[size];
  int subArrayIndex = 0;
  for (int i = index; i < index + size; i++) {
    subArray[subArrayIndex] = array[i];
    subArrayIndex++;
  }
  return subArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's a simple way to do it but I am not allowed to have a method that has a return type of int[] or anything like that in general. I am supposed to make a constructor and do the needful cause I have a method in my code that is `IntSequence subArray(int index, int size)` where IntSequence is an interface and hence the method has an interface return type.

Comment: @user3397222 Just copy this logic into your constructor then and create a getter method for the int[] array that you instantiate with this logic